# Не могу отправить письмо на Ubuntu + Vagrant Swift_TransportException

Tags: php, ubuntu, email, vagrant

Нужно на сайте сделать отправку писем. Работает он на Yii2. Письма отправляю на mailtrap. Однако получаю ошибку

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Но когда запускаю сайт на OpenServer письмо улетает. Сейчас сайт работает на Vagrant + Ubuntu 18.04 + php7.3

Не могу понять проблему

Comment: Проверяйте возможность выяснения доменного IP адреса (DNS network name resolution) с вашего сервера, именно об этом вам и сообщает ошибка с [php_network_getaddresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat)

Answer (score 0):

была проблема с dns. очень просто пофиксил